# Symfony3 multiple update with subquery

Tags: doctrine, sql-update, symfony

Is there ability to make a multiple update with subquery on Symfony3 with Doctrine query builder or DQL?

For example, I want to run this query:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET fieldA2 = max_field2
FROM (SELECT
          field1,
          max(field2) AS max_field2
      FROM table
      GROUP BY field1) AS subquery
WHERE subquery.field1 = tableA.field1;
```

I can't understand how to use `$entityManager->createQuery()->update` with FROM  subquery.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible through DQL.

You need to go through a loop.

```
foreach($entities as entity)
{
    $em->flush();
}
```

Else, you will consider [Batch processing](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html), or just use plain SQL. So it might be usefull to check [DBAL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this loop, because `$em->flush()` just execute several querues (for example updates). So, It doesn't help.

Comment: Batch processing  just controles how much update queries code will execute. It is restriction, but not solution.
Now using plain SQL is the only way, but it is not DQL or QueryBuilder